# Вставка PDF-файла на форму. Ошибка Visual Studio 2015. C#

Tags: c#, pdf

Помогите найти решение проблемы. После того как я пытаюсь перенести на форму с панели элементов Adobe PDF Reader, генерируется ошибка **"Сбой при импорте элемента управления ActiveX. Убедитесь в том, что он правильно зарегистрирован."** Что можно сделать? или может есть способ сделать каким-то другим способом просмотр PDF-файла через форму.

Answer (score 0):

Если не работает через средства Adobe, то можно конвертировать в изображение и выводить через PictureBox, но имхо-это не очень. Можно закинуть браузер на форму и выводить в него. А проще всего просто открывать стороннее приложение(Acrobat Reader) и открывать в нем.